# Prove that In a locally connected space X every component U has the property that {U,X - U} forms a separation of X.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

P rove  that  In a locally connected space X every component U has the property that {U,X-U}  forms a separation of X.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: You probably already know that components are closed, so you need only prove that they are also open. Let $C$ be a component, and suppose that $x\in C$. Then $x$ has a connected nbhd $N$. Show that $C\cup N$ is connected, and then use the fact that $C$ is a component (i.e., not just any connected set) to show that $x$ is in the interior of $C$.